# Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated when attaching an entity to database context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

To attach an entity to database context in entity framework, I use the following:

```
var student = GetStudent();
if (!_dbContext.Students.Local.Any(e => e.ID == student.ID))
    _dbContext.Attach(student);
```

This code **sometimes** (e.g., 1 out of 3) fails with the following error raised when `Attach` is called:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.

Simply re-running this piece of code when exception is thrown, may resolve the issue. However, I interested in knowing why I see this error, what causes it, and how I can resolve it?

(This code belongs to a big project, and I am not sure which parts can help identify the cause of this issue; if you suspect anything, let me know and will share related code.)

Comment: Is this code nested within foreach loop?

Comment: no, its not. It is in a method called by an API controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are re-running the project and it is working as expected i assume this  might be related to caching. Could you please add AsNoTracking() method like this.

```
var student = GetStudent();
if (!_dbContext.Students.AsNoTracking().Local.Any(e => e.ID == student.ID))
    _dbContext.Attach(student);
```

Comment: It says `IQuerable<Students> does not contain a definition for Local`.

Comment: Could you please provides Students and Local models

Comment: `Local` is not my model; its [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.local?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you exact answer for this, but exception explains whats happening. In simple terms your collection is getting changed by other thread when you are trying to attach.

This usually happens when you are using parallel programming. By Debugging you have to identify whats happening underneath of your code and try to resolve it.